# Multiple Instances of CKEditor 5 with React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I have created a React component to use CKEditor 5 in my project. It's working fine for individual instances. But when I try to use multiple instances of this component with a loop, only one instance of the editor is displayed. How can I make it work for multiple instances?

Editor Component:

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

const Editor = ({ data, setData, config = {}, height = "200px" }) => {
    return (
        <CKEditor
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            config={config}
            data={data}
            onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                setData(data);
            }}
            onReady={(editor) => {
                editor.editing.view.change((writer) => {
                    writer.setStyle(
                        "height",
                        height,
                        editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
                    );
                });
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default Editor;
```

Loop in the parent component:

```
{data.map((index, content) => (
    <Box key={index} sx={{ width: "96%" }}>
        <Editor data={content} setData={updateData} />
    </Box>
)}
```

**Note:** I tried to add two instances of the editor without a loop, and it worked fine.